# Xcode asking requires Signing certificates for POD Bundle for ID-Card-scan

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, code-signing

[image]

I updated Xcode 13 to 14.
previously i was able to achieve a build in Xcode 13.
After being updated to Xcode 14 its gives error

> Pods.xcodeproj Signing for "ID-Card-Camera-IDCardCameraResources" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

Comment: go to ```project navigator``` -> ```signing & capabilities``` and select a development team

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add the below code at the end of POD file.
2. Install the pod again
3. Run the app

post_install do |installer|

```
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

end

[image: pic1]